# Showing multiple roles assigned to a user in Laravel using Spatie Permissions

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-permission

does anyone know how to show multiple roles that are under a user? I have setup my permissions so a user can be under multiple roles, which is set easily enough using the following

```
$user->assignRole(['Root', 'IT', 'HR']); // assigning roles
```

I am however having trouble showing all roles a user relongs to in the same way?
Has anyone done this and knows how to? I simply want to show on a page which role a user belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this link

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/basic-usage/basic-usage

Get the names of the user's roles

```
$roles = $user->getRoleNames();
```

Returns a collection

Answer (score 2):

if there are two tables (roles and user_roles) than you can check through inner join ('inner join' to check role must exist in 'roles' table that is assigned to a user) by passing user_id (user_id to get specific roles assigned by a user).

Comment: $get = DB::table('users_roles')
                    ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users_roles.role_id')
                    ->select('roles.id', 'roles.name', 'users_roles.user_id')
                    ->where('users_roles', $req->user_id)
                    ->orderBy('roles.id', 'ASC')
                    ->get();

Answer (score 1):

You can get a collection of roles assigned to the user via `$user->roles`